# Java split string is only keeping one character after split

Tags: java, string, split

I've a simple code:

```
System.out.println("Enter ItemID ~SPACE~ Quantity: ");
String itemInfo = scanner.next();

String[] selectedItem = itemInfo.split("\\s+",2);

System.out.println(selectedItem.length);
System.out.println("The item selected for order is: " + selectedItem[0] + " and the quantity is: " + selectedItem[1]);
```

Let's say user enters `4 6` then the print statements prints `1` and then an error about `Exception in thread "main" java.lang` which basically means `selectedItem[1]` does not exist or is null.

My question is how do I split the string so that when user enters `4 6` it give me `4` and `6` on indexes `0` and `1`?

Comment: Using `scanner.next()` already "splits" around spaces. `Scanner.next()` only reads the next token, where tokens are separated by the scanner's separator which by default includes spaces. Maybe you wanted to use `scanner.nextLine()` ?

Comment: Your code is fine with `String itemInfo = "4 6";` The problem is from your `scanner` has shown by @Aaron.

Comment: Either use `Scanner#nextLine()` to read the whole line and _then_ split the tokens, or read each token via `next()` like you do, then there is no need to split by space.

Answer (score 1):

you have to just change `scanner.next()` to `scanner.nextLine()` and it will be done.